# Checkboxes are not updating in the database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo, mysqli

I've got a question about databases and checkboxes. I've got a table looking like:

[image: table structure]

Website is looking like:

[image: Website screenshot]

At the bottom of the page I also have a button, so when I submit the checked checkboxes will be updated to 1 or 0 in the database. (True or false)

So when I click on the 3rd checkbox under trained, it will update the trained column in the database with a user/room id of '3583'. (ID is shown right of the screen)

Code:

```
<form class='verwerkInfo' method='post' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?license=6'>
                <td>
                    <?php if($room->trained == 1) { ?> <input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>" checked> <?php echo "Y"; } else{ ?> <input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>"> <?php echo "N"; }?> </td>
                <Td><?php if($room->active == 1) { ?> <input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>" checked> <?php echo "Active"; } else { ?> <input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>"  <?php echo "Inactive"; } ?>
                </td>

                <Td><?php echo $room->configuration; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $room->room_id; ?></td>
                <td><?php var_dump($room->user_id); }?></td>
                </tr>
```

So I guess I have a problem in the names of the checkboxes.

The query is looking like:

```
$trainedQuery = "UPDATE room_users
                            SET trained = 1
                            WHERE user_id = $room->user_id";
```

The `$room->user_id` is referring to the user_id in the database.

Comment: In every checkbox, the name of it is always same, room id. Try to add some unique statments to that. Like "n_{room_id}" and the 2nd checkbox "y_{room_id}".

Comment: Can you show us your html form

Comment: I don't have a HTML form, but you can see it in the code ^^ starting with <form> and then the checkboxes look carefully..

Comment: Checkbox name must be unique

Comment: What do you mean @NarendraSisodia Could you explain that?

Comment: Exacly what I have wrote: <input type='checkbox' name="n_<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>" checked> and the other one <input type='checkbox' name="y_<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>" checked>

or you could use array like: name="n[<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>]"

Comment: @SoftGuide It is not working :( I'm clueless right now! working 2 days on this simple function, but it is still not working!!

Comment: Can we see your code that loops through these rows to set each one individually? How does `$room->user_id` get set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to give the checkboxes unique names and pass extra information with each element:

```
name="trained[<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $room->user_id; ?>"
```

Then in the PHP script that processes the form submission you can:

```
foreach ( $_POST['trained'] as $room_id => $user_id ) {
    // This query needs protection from SQL Injection!
    $trainedQuery = "UPDATE room_users SET trained = 1 WHERE user_id = $user_id";
}
```

It's not clear what the relationship is between *room_id* and *user_id* and why you're updating the *room_user* table with only *user_id*. What do you do with the *room_id*?

Is this what you actually need:

```
// This query needs protection from SQL Injection!
$trainedClear = "UPDATE room_users SET trained = 0 WHERE user_id = $user_id";
$db->exec($trainedClear); // first clear all

foreach ( $_POST['trained'] as $room_id => $user_id ) {
    // This query needs protection from SQL Injection!
    $trainedQuery = "UPDATE room_users SET trained = 1 
        WHERE user_id = $user_id AND room_id = $room_id";
    $db->exec($trainedQuery); // then add selections
}
// assuming there's a database connection `$db-exec`.
// Replace with your actual connection and query method.
```

---

Refactored checkbox columns for clarity:

```
<?php

$room_id = $room->id;
$room_configuration = $room->configuration;
$room_user_id = $room->user_id;

if ( $room->trained == 1 ) {
    $trained_checked = 'checked';
    $trained_label = 'Y';
}
else {
    $trained_checked = '';
    $trained_label = 'N';
}

if ( $room->active == 1 ) {
    $active_checked = 'checked';
    $active_label = 'Active';
}
else {
    $active_checked = '';
    $active_label = 'Inactive';
}

echo <<<EOT

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="trained[$room_id]" value="$room_user_id" $trained_checked> $trained_label</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="active[$room_id]" value="$room_user_id" $active_checked> $active_label</td>
    <td>$room_configuration</td>
    <td>$room_id</td>
    <td>$room_user_id</td>

EOT;

?>
```

Comment: It is good solution, but before foreach he should also set all "trained" to 0 over all users. So that he can also remove the check :-)

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the undesired result?

Comment: It is just reloading the webpage, because I ran the php script in the same page.. But i've got more php scripts, would that be a problem? The database is not updating

Comment: It gives me a Fatal error: Call to undefined method db::exec() error @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: You have to use your own database connections. I don't know what they are because you didn't put those in your post.

Comment: Oh, I see it.. I didn't have PDO installed, and I followed the PDO standards.. I had a own function for executing. It is working thanks!!

Comment: Cool! You can use this method with any database connection. *PDO* and *MySQLi* are great for protecting your queries from SQL injection too!

Comment: @Tayk: as an addendum to this poster's comments, I recommend you don't use the phrase "it's not working". We sometimes say here that it's "the least helpful fault report possible", and for good reason: it contains no new information, by itself, for someone to respond to. In future if you can explain _how_ something is not working (error messages, for example) that can be very helpful. Also, as you discovered, using an answer as a jumping-off point for new experimentation is also a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the checkbox names attribute with adding yes,no and active

```
  name="yes_<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>"
  name="no_<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>"
  name="act_<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>"
```

Comment: and further in the code? I tried but didn't work, could you brief a bit more please? I appericiate that:)

Comment: Please tell me on submit what are the value are you sending.

Comment: you can check if(isset($_POST['yes_']) )   {         // do write your code here for the Trained Yes condition     }